Are relic neutrinos gravitationally bound to large scale structures?
I have been interested in how neutrinos arrange themselves around gravitational potentials. However, I found contradictory claims and I would like to clarify this
After reading a bit into this paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.12430) I contacted the authors of it, and they told me that no neutrinos would he gravitationally bound even to the largest structures like superclusters.
However, then, I found a bunch of other papers claiming how would relic neutrinos (that would not be longer relativistic due to the redshift suffered to their momentun by the expansion of the universe):
https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.02860
https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.13388
https://arxiv.org/abs/2306.16444
Then, what is happening? Aren't they contradicting each other? Are there neutrinos gravitationally bound to massive structures or not?

Would you trust an answer from SE more than published research? :p

If very slow relic neutrinos exist then they should be gravitationally bound in deep gravitational wells. That's not very interesting physics, is it?

@MariusLadegårdMeyer the thing is that I have published research papers contradicting each other. One says that relic neutrinos are gravitationally bound to structures while the other says that no neutrinos will be bound to anything. Who is right?

Related question by the OP on our sister site: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/57778/16685

@vengaq exactly, which implies that this is not a cut-and-dried case. Therefore, it is unlikely that an answer on SE has the power to settle the case ;) of course, getting perspectives is always good.
